# Do I have to create custom definition for Firebase reserved parameters (Analytics)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase Analytics for My Android project. There I have a login functionality and I need to track it. So I've used the preserved event and parameter from Firebase. [Link here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events#login).

```
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.LOGIN) {
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.METHOD, source)
}
```

As you see I'm using `FirebaseAnalytics.Event` and `FirebaseAnalytics.Param`. It's preserved in Firebase.
As mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en&utm_id=ad) : `You don't need to set up custom dimensions and metrics for data collected through automatically collected events, enhanced measurement, and recommended events.` So I didn't create a custom dimension for parameter `FirebaseAnalytics.Param.METHOD`, because the Login event is a recommended event.

But when I watch my login event in the firebase dashboard and go into details, I can't find the `method` parameter. I need to know which social media do users use mostly to login. But now I only see, how many login events happened. I can't see the source. So do I need to add the preserved parameters in custom dimensions as well?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the support team:

> All the parameters you’ve associated
> with the event are custom events even if it is included in Firebase’s
> predefined parameter. The only difference is that Firebase’s
> predefined parameters have specific uses that maximize your event
> reports. So to conclude, though you are using
> FirebaseAnalytics.Param.METHOD which is listed in Firebase’s
> predefined parameters, you should still need to associate it with a
> custom definition in order for it to appear in your events report.